# C++ Error: 'no match for operator<...'

Tags: c++, c++11, passwords, generator, brute-force

I have been attempting to create a password generator. The program is supposed to take input, and put out every possible combo of characters (brute force without the force). I am encountering this error: error: no match for 'operator<=' in 'i <= pear'

I have no idea what to do. However, here is the code. Please let me know if I also messed up on anything else, but the error described is the main problem right now:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void generate() {
    int i=0;
    string pass;
    string r;
    string pear;
    for(i=0; i <= pear; i++) {
        pear = pass;
            r = pass[i];
}


    return r;
}

int main() {
    int i;
    string apple;
    cin >> apple;
    generate(apple,i);
    cout << apple;
}
```

Comment: `i` is an int, `pear` is an unset  string. What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: Do not try to learn C++ by trial and error, nothing good will come from that. Get a good book instead.

Comment: I hate to sound like a dick, but this program is complete and utter gibberish.

Comment: You can't compare an integer, `i`, to a string, `pear` in your `for` loop.  It doesn't make sense.

Comment: I don't blame you that this is literally the worst program ever written, I threw this together thinking it would work, didn't find a solution... so I came here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//...    
generate(apple,i);
//...
```

you have to specify the arguments in the signature of your function 'generate' like:

```
void generate( string apple, int it ) {
```

And the error:

```
size_t i;
//...
for(i=0; i <= pear.length(); i++) {
   //logic here?!
}
```

you add an element to a string using:

```
string.push_back( 'a' );
```